# Enlace interno sin modificar la Url HTML

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, url

Tengo varios enlaces internos a ciertos id en la misma página con la etiqueta a href="#seccion1"  en react.
Quisiera saber si con Javascript o JSX puedo evitar que se modifique la url al oprimir un enlace, mis url quedan así: [www.pagina.com/#seccion1](http://www.pagina.com/#seccion1) , no quiero que se agregue el #seccion1.
En esta página vi esa idea: https://www.rudegolems.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes usar la función scrollIntoView pasándole el id del botón, por ejemplo:

Agregar los botones o enlaces a usar:

```
<a class="desplazar" moveTo="Desplazar1" href="#">Desplazar 1</a>
<a class="desplazar" moveTo="Desplazar2" href="#">Desplazar 2</a>
```

A estos le pasamos un atributo llamado `moveTo` que guardara el ID del anclaje

Agregamos nuestros items con el ID del ancla

```
<div id="Desplazar1" style="margin-top: 400px;height: 300px;background: #000;color: #fff;">Desplazar 1</div>
<div id="Desplazar2" style="margin-top: 200px;height: 300px;background: #000;color: #fff;">Desplazar 2</div>
```

luego obtenemos todos los enlaces con la clase `.desplazar`

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll( '.desplazar' );
```

Luego usando `forEach` recorremos todos los enlaces.

```
links.forEach( link =>{
    link.addEventListener( "click",_ => {
            
    });
});
```

Y aqui viene la magia, usamos

```
event.preventDefault()
```

para eliminar el evento por defecto, luego, al objeto actual le extraemos nuestro ID a desplazar usando `getAttribute`

```
let moveTo = link.getAttribute( 'moveTo' );
```

Y por ultimo hacemos el scroll usando `scrollIntoView`

```
document.getElementById( moveTo ).scrollIntoView(true);
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll( '.desplazar' );

    links.forEach( link =>{
        link.addEventListener( "click",_ => {
            
            event.preventDefault();
            let moveTo = link.getAttribute( 'moveTo' );
            document.getElementById( moveTo ).scrollIntoView(true);

        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a class="desplazar" moveTo="Desplazar1" href="#">Desplazar 1</a>
    <a class="desplazar" moveTo="Desplazar2" href="#">Desplazar 2</a>

    <div style="margin-top: 400px;height: 300px;background: #000;color: #fff;" id="Desplazar1">Desplazar 1</div>
    
  <div style="margin-top: 200px;height: 300px;background: #000;color: #fff;" id="Desplazar2">Desplazar
  2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Esto debería permitirte desplazarte a las anclas sin comprometer las urls.

Comment: Si me funciono, muchas gracias.